# Insert linkedlist recursively in descending order

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I'm learning java and trying to implement a Java 'LinkedList' insertList method. I want it to it to work recursivly and in the descending order. I was following a book's tutorial but I'm stuck at this point. I have the following codes below now, which is not working properly. Can anyone give me some advice about this?

Say, we want to insert 1, 3, 9, 0, 5 to the 'LinkedList'. After running the code, it should be 9, 5, 3, 1, 0 in the 'LinkedList'.

```
public class ListElement {
    int value
    ListElement next;
}

public static ListElement InsertList(ListElement head, ListElement elem) { 

    if(head == null){
        elem.next = head;
        return elem;
    }
    else{
        if(elem.value > head.value){
        elem.next = InsertList(elem, head.next);
    }else{
        elem.next = InsertList(head.next, elem);
    }
        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of ListElement ? What is this function 'insert' that you call twice ?

Comment: @vtheron Hi,thanks for the quick reply. I added the ListElement in my question. The insert function is to insert a new element in the linkedlist..

Comment: OK, but where is the code for insert ?

Comment: @vtheron  function InsertList(ListElement head, ListElement elem) is for insert.

Comment: as you are learning java -- use proper naming convensions `InsertList` should be `insertList`

Comment: Please provide a precise specification for the method. Just using the name and arguments isn't sufficient to understand what it's supposed to do. Example inputs and outputs would help understanding what you want to achieve. After that is done, explain what the problem is with the code you have. Just saying "it doesn't work" isn't helpful. Chances are that just doing all this will make you find how to do it correctly.

Comment: No, vtheron means the function you call when you say `insert(head.next, elem)` - what is this function? It has a different name to `InsertList`...

Comment: if your function is called InsertList why do you call it with insert ? Does your code even compile ?

Comment: @vtheron Sorry that's a typo. It's InsertList in my code. I basically re-type them here.

Comment: Do you know what *recursion* is?  Please show us where it is used in your code.

Comment: @PM77-1  elem.next = InsertList(elem, head.next); here is the recursion part

Comment: What is that supposed to be : elem.next > head ? Can you really use the > operator with instances of ListElement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has several problems. The test

```
      if(elem.next > head){
```

shouldn't compile, because the `>` operator is not defined for objects. It also seem that you have no base case for your recursion—you recurse in all cases, which will cause a stack overflow. Finally, should be inserting a value, not an instance of `ListElement`. Try this instead (I renamed the method to `insertList` to conform with Java coding conventions):

```
public static ListElement insertList(ListElement head, int value) { 
    ListElement elt;
    if (head == null || head.value <= value) {
        elt = new ListElement();
        elt.value = value;
        elt.next = head;
        return elt;
     } else {
        head.next = insertList(head.next, value);
        return head;
     }
}
```

The advantage of inserting a value instead of a `ListElement` is that you can hide the implementation of the list from client code. Also, since a `ListElement` might be an entire list, inserting a `ListElement` might have unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is not strictly important, but java conventions impose that methods starts with lower case letter.

Second, maybe instead of insert, you want to call insertList (your own function), which makes the function recursive and sensible.

Third, you must compare values:

```
if (head == null || elem.value > head.value){
    elem.next = head;
    return elem;
}
else {
    head.next = insertList(head.next, elem);
    return head;
}
```

This means: if head is null or is smaller than elem, insert elem at start; otherwise, insert it in the continuation of the list.

Comment: I think so. if elem is bigger than head, it will become first, keeping descending order. otherwise, head will remain first, and check will go to the second element via recursion.

Comment: Yeah it looks fine but I tried it in my complier. It's still remaining the order of the array itself. Say i push 5.3 1 2 8. The linkedlist is 5 3 1 2 8..